# AngularJS - how to change controller when user types in text box

Tags: angularjs

HTML body code.

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'  style="background-color:#006633;">
                <div class='col-md-6'>
                    <input style="margin-top:10px;" type="text" ng-model="SearchText" placeholder="Search for more than 10,000 products..." class='form-control' size="50">
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-2'>
                    <a ui-sref="Login" style="position:absolute; margin-top:15px; color:#FFFCBA"><strong>LOGIN</strong></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="middle" class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div id="right" class='col-md-10'>
                    <div ui-view></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Routing Code

```
sampleApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Products/38/");
    $stateProvider
        .state('Products', {
            templateUrl: "templates/Products.html",
            url: '/Products/:SCID/:BrandID',
            controller: 'ProductsController as pc'
        })
        .state('Login', {
            templateUrl: "templates/Login.html",
            url: "/Login",
            controller: 'LoginController'
        });
});
```

Controller

```
sampleApp.controller('ProductsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $log, $rootScope, $stateParams, ProductService) {
    $scope.$on('SearchTextChanged', function(event, SearchText) {
        if (SearchText.length >=3)  {
            $scope.FilterExpr = SearchText;
        }
    });
});
```

Products.html template

```
<div ng-if="SearchText.length>=3" class='box' ng-repeat="product in pc.ProductService.Products | filter:FilterExpr | orderBy:'ProductName'">
    <ng-include src="'commonTemplate.html'"></ng-include>
</div>
```

Every thing works fine until user click on login button. once user click on login button, controller moves to LoginController.

Now if user types in text box for searching the products, i want again product controller to be loaded to display the products.

How to do that? Any help?

Comment: while clicking login you are redirecting to login.html don't you? so how can you search product in there?

Comment: @OriPrice, you are right. I am redirecting to login.html; But when user starts typing in text box, i again wants to redirect to Products.html. That is what i want to know how to do that?

Comment: could you add Login.html and maybe Products.html so we can understand a bit more?

Comment: Products.html already added. And i don't think,  it matters what's in login.html

Comment: Could you produce a working plunker that demonstrates the issue? I tried to myself but you haven't given us all the pieces of the puzzle (what's in MainCtrl?) so it's not easy. To be honest I think you have a lot overall design issues that, were they to be addressed, would make things like this trivial. Specifically, you should look into using nested states which could help you move away from relying `$scope.$.on()` event listeners to communicate between controllers, which is a huge code smell in my opinion. That's just my opinion but I do think we really need a live demo to help you on this.

Comment: doesn't make sense that as soon as user starts typing a redirect occurs. This is very unfriendly user experience and will be confusing

Comment: I feel like you are asking how to do a typeahead; where you go searching for a list of products based on what the user is typing.  I don't think you mean to ask how to "change controllers"; you seem to have your terminology mixed up.